# Quoting the expanded value of a macro

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, c-preprocessor, stringification

This is driving me nuts. I have a macro defined on the command line with the `-D` option

```
-DFOO="foobarbaz"
```

And then I want to do something like this

```
string s = "FOO" ;
```

To get

```
string s = "foobarbaz" ;
```

Because apparently the quotes from the command line are stripped away, even when I try to escape them with `\`. I've tried everything I could think with stringification and additional macros and it just won't work. Either I get an error from the preprocessor about misplaced `#` signs, or I end up with

```
string s = foobarbaz ;
```

which obviously won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this on the command line:

```
-DFOO="\"hello world\""
```

For example test.cpp is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string test = FOO;

int main()
{
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running gives:

```
$ g++ -DFOO="\"hello world\"" test.cpp
$ ./a.out 
hello world
```

**EDIT** This is how you would do it from a Makefile:

```
DEFS=-DFOO="\"hello world\""

test: test.cpp
    $(CXX) $(DEFS) -o test test.cpp
```

Comment: Your example works, but when I do the exact same thing in my actual program the quotes are stripped right off. Perhaps it's because I use Make? Is Make stripping off quotes?

Comment: @ADCoon I have updated my answer.  You need to mention you are using a Makefile in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I found the error, it was a silly mistake in the makefile

Comment: You've given him the fish. It would have been better to show him how to fish, instead.

Answer (score 0):

The C and C++ preprocessors are tuned to C and C++, they are *not* raw, byte-by-byte preprocessors. They recognize strings (as in `"foo"`) and won't match and expand within them. If you want to expand a macro, you must do it outside a string. E.g.,

```
#define foo "bar"

#include <string>

int main () {
    std::string s = "Hello " foo "! How's it going?";
}
```

Above string would expand to

```
Hello bar! How's it going?
```